# Cosine similarity with recentering - collaborative filtering

Tags: normalization, recommender-system, centering, cosine-similarity

I don’t know much about stats (nor maths), so I’m sorry if I’m not being very clear on this...
I’m trying to build a simple recommender system for books using collaborative filtering item by item.
I’ve used cosine similarity to get the similarity between books. Then, I found out that, as I have (a lot of) missing ratings, I need to recenter/normalize the vectors, which I did.

But in the end, I find the results very intriguing. Here is an example:

|  | user 1 | user 2 | user 3 | user 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| book 1 | 2 | null | null | 3 |
| book 2 | 4 | null | null | 3 |
| book 3 | 1 | 2 | null | null |

After normalization :

|  | user 1 | user 2 | user 3 | user 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| book 1 | -0.5 | null | null | 0.5 |
| book 2 | 0.5 | null | null | -0.5 |
| book 3 | -0.5 | 0.5 | null | null |

Then the results for cosine similarity are :

- book 1 - book 2 = -1
- book 1 - book 3 = 0.5

I would naturally say that the result between book 1 and 2 should be 0.5 as one of the ratings is similar, but of course, the normalization changes it all.
Could anybody tell me if the results are fine (and my sample is simply too small) or, if not, which solution I have? Drop the normalization or just completely change my method?